# Uploading a 7 years old published conference paper on arXiv

Tags: publications, conference, arxiv

I have 3 conference papers which were published around 7 years ago. However, the conference proceedings are not well indexed. If I upload a 7 year old published work on arXiv to increase the audiences, will the research community take this action positively or negatively?

Comment: Have you checked the copyright terms and conditions of the conference?

Comment: Yes I checked and they allow to upload with condition to add a link to conference proceedings.

Comment: I cannot imagine a negative response.  The worst is: no one cares.

Comment: It's not uncommon. (eg https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05741). As long as you make it clear in the comment section that's completely fine.

Comment: @John Ma, would you consider posting your comment as an answer? In fact it is a good one and the question would no longer appear in the "unanswered questions" section ;-)